# Finding TextBox inside of UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I have built an example application which has custom UserControl inside Windows Form. UserControl consists of two controls: Button and TextBox.

I can find textbox by providing only type and this works:

```
var customUserControlTextBox = new WinEdit(parentWindow);
customUserControlTextBox.Text = "Some value";
```

But why Coded UI cannot find the TextBox if I add another search parameter:

```
customUserControlTextBox.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ControlName, "UserControlTextBox");
```

Test will fail in message: "The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details:
**TechnologyName**: MSAA,
**ControlType**: Edit,
**ControlName**: UserControlTextBox

Here is image capture from Coded UI Test Builder:

[image: TextBox has control specific property ControlName...]

In this Microsoft blog page, its said that SearchParameters should act like AND operator:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/balagans/2009/12/28/how-does-coded-ui-test-finds-a-control/

*First pass of the Search is done for the match of All properties given in SearchProperties list. Basically this can be referred as AND Condition of search properties.*

Comment: My guess is that the control you added to the UIMap is slightly different from the control that could be found at runtime, e.g. having a other value for the ControlName property. If you did not already try, you could fetch that control on runtime in a debug session through .GetChildren() on the parent and navigate the found controls and properties until you find the controlname property for the control you are looking for. The visual studio watch is very useful for that.

Comment: I'm not using UIMap. My test is purely hand written.

Comment: But did you compare your search properties against the properties of the control you wish to find at runtime? The only logical explanation I could find is that at least one of your search properties must be different from what you have set as searchproperty on your `customUserControlTextBox`, hence the error.

Comment: It seems that TextBox (WinEdit) have only two SearchProperties which is usable:
ControlType and TechnologyName. If I search first for the parent window of textbox (frame around the textbox) and then just fetch textbox inside that frame it will work.

It is just bit funny that textbox cannot be found directly from form, you have to first find the frame window.